# Link xib file with UIViewController and Custom Class

Tags: swift, uiview, xib, swift2

To create the xib file I add a new cocoa touch file subclass of UIViewController, and checked the "Also Create XIB file".

There is only one label in my xib file.

In my view controller :

```
import UIKit

class TestControllerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Nothing else than my IBoutlet (I checked the connection Inspector 10 times at least).

And My custom class :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class Card: UIView {
    internal var number:Int?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    convenience init()
    {
        self.init()
    }

}

extension UIView {
    class func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> UIView? {
        return UINib(
            nibName: nibNamed,
            bundle: bundle
            ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    }
}
```

I instantiate this xib file in my initial viewController :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var test:Card = Card.loadFromNibNamed("TestControllerViewController")! as! Card
        test.number = 18
        //self.view.addSubview(test)
    }
```

And I still have this error :

`2015-07-27 17:48:52.919 TestXib[6865:578635] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fcec14b1970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'`

I don't know why, I tried to clean / rebuild, delete DerivedData, create the xib file again etc.

Could you please help me ?

Thank's.
Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You handle wrong way. A custom `UIView` from xib of another `UIViewController` will confuse. But I will take you out of this bug. See setting below.

[image]

Change `FileOwner` from `TestControllerViewController` to `Card`
[image]
Remove `Outlet` reference:
[image]

Change main view to `Card`. It's help you cast `UIView` to `Card`.

[image]

BTW: I advice you create new xib file `Card.xib` and connect it with `Card.swift`

Comment: Yes thank you, I did this, and linked my action (addTarget ..) from this Card to a specific ViewController, and all is working properly. Thank you @longpham.